# Changing colors of entries of a matrix in Maple

Tags: maple

I need to make distinction between certain entries of a matrix that are identical. The only practical solution I can think of is to use different color. Can someone please tell me how to modify the color of individual entries of a matrix in Maple? I checked the "options" and none of them seems to be controlling color. (Changing the color of the entries of the entire matrix will not do any good)

Comment: Why does the location $ij$ not distinguish them?

Comment: It's too much of data recording when you  have massive Excel output. I can only afford one line per case and need to see right at the spot who is who.

Comment: What does "one line per case" mean? If your output is an excel range you know where everything is - you know the location of cell(i, j)?

Comment: These are coefficients of a polynomial. If I knew how they are expressed in terms of i,j I wouldn't be asking this question.

Comment: What I have is therefore a vector, if you like, but it doesn't matter as far as my question about modifying color is concerned. I am not able to tell the degrees of terms with identical coefficients in terms of $(i,j)$, that's the problem.

Comment: would you have an example polynomial, the vector you create from it and the problem that arises (and how excel then fits in)? Maybe something could be done at the excel end.

Comment: That's it! You've got it. Thank you very much. That solves the problem.

Comment: See `ExcelTools:-Export`